# DynamoDB Access Pattern

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm trying to familiarize myself with DynamoDB and I'm facing the following problem.
My data record looks like this:

```
Crew{
  id: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  email: string,
  roles: Role[],
  address: Address
}

Role{
  name: string
}

Address{
  street: string,
  zipCode: string,
  city: string,
  countryIsoCode: string
}
```

In DynamoDB, it would look like this:

| PK | SK | GSI_PK1 | GSI_SK1 | GSI_PK2 | GSI_SK2 | Entity | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| crewID#1 | crew |  |  |  | Crew |  | {firstName: 'Lex', lastName:'Luther', email: 'lext_luther@test.com', roles:[actor, director, writer]} |
| crewID#2 | crew |  |  |  | Crew |  | {firstName: 'Bruce', lastName:'Wayne', email: 'batman@test.com', roles:[actor]} |
| crewReqID#1 | req |  |  | CrewReq | CrewReq#2023-06-28-18:00:05 |  | {title: 'Batman Begins', shootingStart:'fall',crewReq:[ crewID#2, crewID#10]} |

I have the following access patterns that I need to solve without using a scan or multiple queries:

1. I want to retrieve all Crew items that have roles x, y, or n.
2. I want to retrieve all Crew items that have roles x, y, or n but do not
   appear in the crewReq attribute of crewReq#.
3. I want to retrieve a specific crew item.

I thought about removing the 'roles' attribute from the 'Data' field and writing the item to the DB for each role once. This way, I could at least solve the first and third access pattern in a single query. However, I'm not sure how to solve the second requirement yet.

Moreover, it seems like this approach might be incorrect. I also believe that a third GSI (Global Secondary Index) is unnecessary.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use DynamoDB here? DynamoDB might not be the right technology for this use case.